# Как запустить 2 потока одновременно?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Consumer из rabbitmq считывает данные из записывает его в jobs. В данной реализации consumer работает, а метод `do_stuff` никак не реагирует

```
import threading
jobs = Queue()

def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        logger.info('received new task')
        value = q.get()
        url = value['download_link']
        
        driver = uc.Chrome(headless = False)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", params)
        driver.set_window_size(200, 400)
        driver.get(url)
        
        wait_page_download_finished(driver)
        waiting = WebDriverWait(driver, 300, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
        table.insert(q)
        q.task_done()


for i in range(3):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs,))
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()
    worker.join(0)
    
def callbackFunctionForQueueC(ch,method,properties,body):
    logger.info('received message')
    message = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))
    jobs.put(message)
    
    
connection= pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel= connection.channel()
channel.basic_consume(queue='item', on_message_callback=callbackFunctionForQueueC, auto_ack=True)


t1 = Thread(target= channel.start_consuming)
t1.start()
t1.join(0)
```

Comment: Потоки завершаются сразу после запуска из-за пустой очереди.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы оно ждало появления новых данных?

Comment: Можно использовать переменные состояния.

Comment: одновременно никак, можно синхронизировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но ведь в документации на `Queue` есть [пример](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join), как правильно работать с очередью:

```py
import threading
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        print(f'Working on {item}')
        print(f'Finished {item}')
        q.task_done()

# Turn-on the worker thread.
threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

# Send thirty task requests to the worker.
for item in range(30):
    q.put(item)

# Block until all tasks are done.
q.join()
print('All work completed')
```

Основной смысл тут в том, что не нужно ориентироваться на `empty()`, а нужно делать `task_done()`, а в основном коде сделать `join()` к очереди и тогда, пока очередь не разгребётся, это всё будет работать. Хотя если у вас вдруг очередь разгребается быстрее, чем пополняется, то и этот вариант не сработает как нужно. Возможно, тогда вам нужно договориться с собой о том, что когда пополнение очереди закончится, вы положите в неё специальный элемент, например `None`, за наличием которого и будете следить при разгребании очереди, чтобы закончить её обработку, когда достанете этот элемент из очереди.

Comment: У него задания приходят извне. Именно поэтому нельзя на пустоту очереди закладываться, ни правильным способом (как в документации), ни неправильным (как у него).

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Ну вот понять бы, как там собственно должны задания заканчиваться.

Answer (score 0):

```
while not q.empty():
```

выход из потока сразу, ведь поток запустился с пустой очередью. используйте пустую посылку для завершения тредов например

```
def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        logger.info('received new task')
        value = q.get()
        if not value:
            q.task_done()
            break
        url = value['download_link']
        
        driver = uc.Chrome(headless = False)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", params)
        driver.set_window_size(200, 400)
        driver.get(url)
        
        wait_page_download_finished(driver)
        waiting = WebDriverWait(driver, 300, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
        table.insert(q)
        q.task_done()
```

Но так как у вас сообщения берутся с внешнего источника, то эти пустые сообщения вставляешь через обработчик для модуля signal для плавного завершения работы

Comment: пустую посылку?